# Resolving Windows Shares

Tags: networking, share, dns

RPi can access smb://$server/$share no problem through file manager

RPi can not resolve //$server/$share

RPi can not ping/nslookup //$server/$share

RPi can ping IP address of //$server

Looking like a DNS issue. How would I go about resolving this? Don't want to specify WINS or a DNS server.

Answer (score 1):

installing these helps resolve windows hostnames:

```
sudo apt-get install samba winbind
sudo nano /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

and change 'hosts: files dns' TO 'hosts: files wins dns'

if your rpi is on a static ip you may have to add the dns server in the /etc/resolve.conf

Answer (score 1):

I would not expect **//$server/$share** to resolve *as a host name* using DNS or WINS. **$server** is (presumably) the host name. It looks like you can ping it by name (e.g. **ping server**) by omitting the **$share** and extraneous '**/**' portions of the commands that fail, so you are getting name resolution. That would be the expected result.